# python gnupg multiple recipient encryption

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I am trying to work with python-gnupg and I am having trouble with encrypting a file with multiple keys. I have seen a couple 'man pages' on the subject, and I am following https://www.red-dove.com/python_gnupg/index.html#encryption-and-decryption since it matches best. Apparently, I am supposed to put keyIDs in a list, but when I do, gnupg fails. However, if I only give one keyid as an argument, everything is peachy.
For example, in a quick'n dirty bpython session:

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> gpg=gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/fred/.gnupg')
>>> stream=open('../../README', 'r+')
>>> t=['1BFA0C4BDED1F993, F8DE6324AB01797D']
>>> encrypted=gpg.encrypt(stream, t , always_trust=True, output='test.gpg')
>>> encrypted.ok
False
>>> encrypted.stderr
u"gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input\n"
>>> stream=open('../../README', 'r+')
>>> encrypted=gpg.encrypt(stream, '1BFA0C4BDED1F993' , always_trust=True, output='test.gpg')
>>> encrypted.ok
True
>>> encrypted.stderr
u'[GNUPG:] PROGRESS need_entropy X 8 16\n[GNUPG:] PROGRESS need_entropy X 16 16\n[GNUPG:] BEGIN_ENCRYPTION 2 9\n[GNUPG:] END_ENCRYPTION\n'
```

I have tried different permutation, forcing t to be a string and splitting it every which way (since the doc for python-gnupg varies widely, but I can't seem to get anything encrypted with more than one key, which is somewhat problematic for what I am currently working on.

I am wondering if anybody has any experience with that one.

Comment: If `t` should be a list, shouldn't you use `t=['1BFA0C4BDED1F993', 'F8DE6324AB01797D']`? Currently, you pass a single element string containing both keys.

Comment: You are entirely correct... I went way too quickly when writing the 'proof of concept'.
However, the problem remains even after I fixed my list:
    >>> stream=open('../../README', 'r+')
    >>> t=['1BFA0C4BDED1F993', 'F8DE6324AB01797D']
    >>> encrypted=gpg.encrypt(stream,t , always_trust=True, output='test.gpg')
    >>> encrypted.ok
    False
    >>> encrypted.stderr
    u"gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input\n"
    >>>

Comment: Found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer?questionid=19298171&reason=thankyou&s=4a113932-2c5f-44b3-8898-788c2947c47d
too bad I had not seen it when I search from stackoverflow...

Comment: Are both of those key fingerprints for public keys?  Usually the no terminal thing means it wants to run pinentry to get you to provide a passphrase.

It's also possible that those keys fingerprints are to keys not found in your keyring?

Does this work for you:

gpg --recv-key F8DE6324AB01797D
gpg --recv-key 1BFA0C4BDED1F993
gpg --encrypt --recipient F8DE6324AB01797D --recipient 1BFA0C4BDED1F993 --armor --export /etc/hosts > foo.asc

That sets you up to have a working gpg setup for the keys you are trying to use.

Comment: @WayneWalker Thanks for the tip. Sadly no joy. It works fine form the cli, but python is still giving me the cold shoulder :( 
[link](http://pastebin.com/Jm8EiYLJ) for the details

Comment: I ended up switching to an older fork of the module, which happens to have a encrypt_file method that actually works and accepts a list argument for the recipients.... So yay!